# How to create a loop for plotting dataframe features in Python using seaborn

Tags: python

I would like to plot multiple subplot of histogram to observe the distribution of each individual features in a data frame.

I have tried to use the below code, but it says dataframe object has no attribute i. I know the code is wrong somewhere, but i have tried to search for solution and could not find a way to generate a loop for this.

```
for i in enumerate(feature):
   plt.subplot(3,3, i[0]+1)
   sns.histplot(df.i[i], kde=True)
```

Comment: Try sns.pairplot

Comment: Hi @helloworld, i have tried using sns.pairplot but it gave me additional plot which i'm not interested in. I would only like to see the histogram plot to observe the normal distribution.

Comment: Does the below answer help your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.plot.hist(subplots=True, legend=False)
```

Seaborn alternative

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='column')
g.map(plt.hist, 'value')
```